# hive ip geocoding (cross join semi-big tables)

Tags: hadoop, hive, ip-geolocation

My problem.

I have 500,000 distinct IP address I need to geocode. The Geocode look up table have an ip-from and ip-to range that I have to compare against, a table of 1.8 million rows.

So it's basically:

```
select *
/*+ MAPJOIN(a) */
from ip_address a
cross join  ip_lookup b
where a.AddressInt >= b.ip_from and a.AddressInt <= b.ip_to;
```

On aws EMR, I'm running a cluster of 10 m1.large and during the cross join phase it gets stuck at 0% for 20 min but here's the funny thing:

```
Stage-5: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
```

Questions:
1) any one have any better ideas than a cross join? I don't mind firing up a few (dozen) more instances but I doubt that will help and
2) am I REALLY doing a cross map join as in storing the ip_addresses in the memory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had your (kind of) problem last year.

Since my geocode table fitted in RAM here's what I did:

1. I've written Java class (let's call it `GeoCoder`) that read geocode info from the disc into RAM and 
   did geocoding in-memory.
2. I've added file `geocode.info` to the distributed cache (Hive `add file` command does this).
3. I've written `UDF` that created (or used if it was already created) `GeoCoder` instance in the `evaluate` method. Hive `UDF` can get the local path of the file in the distributed cache via `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("geocode.info").getFile()`
4. Now I have the local path of `geocode.info` (now it's an ordinary file) and the rest is a history.

Probably this method is an overkill (150 lines of Java) but it worked for me.

Also I assume that you really need to use Hadoop (like I did) for your task.
Geocoding of 500000 IPs could probably be done on laptop pretty fast.